# Python3.7 pressing left key in console prints ^[[D instead of moving cursor

Tags: 16.04, python

It looks like this:

```
sanyash@sanyash-ub16:~$ python3.7
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar 12 2019, 20:13:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
<press left key>
>>> ^[[D
```

What is it? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you build it yourself (since the default version for 16.04 is only 3.5 iirc)? if so, did you enable readline support?

Comment: Yes, I built it from source, but I don't know about readline support

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/893053/4464570 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495655/4464570